# What repository do i need to add to install java-package on Debian Lenny?

Tags: debian, java, repository

I am trying to install java on my debian machine, and have found several how to's but

```
sudo apt-get install java-package
```

gives me "Couldn't find package java-package".  Do I need to add a repository in my /etc/apt/sources.list file?  Here are the current repos i have.

```
tone@homeserver:/etc/apt$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.4 _Lenny_ - Official amd64 CD Binary-1 20100131-21:33]/ lenny main

deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.4 _Lenny_ - Official amd64 CD Binary-1 20100131-21:33]/ lenny main

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ lenny main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ lenny main

deb http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main

deb http://volatile.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main
deb-src http://volatile.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main
tone@homeserver:/etc/apt$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add contrib to your package list. So:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ lenny main contrib
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ lenny main contrib
```

Comment: Hmm... I added those and double checked spelling, etc but still get same message

Comment: Did you run apt-get update after adding it? http://packages.debian.org/lenny/java-package says it's part of contrib, so it should do it.

Answer (score 1):

The packages for sun jdk/jre on debian are named `sun-java$version-*`, if you want to install the sun java 5 jre then its `sun-java5-jre` that will install the necessary packages.

You can find packages for debian usint their [package search](http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages) site that helps a lot.

EDIT: also, if you search the site I linked above you will see that sun-java packages are on the *non-free* suite, and you need to add then to your apt sources file.